# How to execute parallel scenarios(python BDD) using behavex

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

I have developed selenium script with help of BDD python. I can able to run the scripts using behave. Now I have to run the scenarios parallelly. Behave is the wrapper which provides capability to run scenarios/features parallelly. I have reviewed the documentation. When i am trying to run the scenarios parallelly, I am getting below issue.

behavex documentation link: https://behavex.readthedocs.io/
feature file location: <project_name>\features\

**Script in feature file**
Feature: Testing scenarios

```
 @TAG_1
 Scenario: Scenario1
     ----------
     ----------

 @TAG_1
 Scenario: Scenario2
     -----------
     -----------
```

**Command executed for parallel scenario execution on root directory**

behavex .<project_name>\features\ -t @TAG_1 --parallel-processes 2 --parallel-scheme scenario

After executing the above command, 2 browsers are launching. **But after, getting below issue and scenarios are being skipped . **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts\behavex-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('behavex==2.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'behavex')())
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\runner.py", line 84, in main
    exit_code = run(args)
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\runner.py", line 114, in run
    return launch_behavex()
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\runner.py", line 179, in launch_behavex
    wrap_up_process_pools(process_pool, json_reports, multiprocess, scenario)
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\runner.py", line 428, in wrap_up_process_pools
    generate_reports(merged_json)
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\utils.py", line 435, in generate_reports
    report_html.generate_report(json_output)
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\outputs\report_html.py", line 32, in generate_report
    html = export_result_to_html(
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\outputs\report_html.py", line 134, in export_result_to_html
    output_text = template_handler.render_template(
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\outputs\jinja_mgr.py", line 92, in render_template
    return str(self.get_template(str(template_name)).render(parameter_template))
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1301, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\outputs\jinja\main.jinja2", line 481, in top-level template code
    {{ line|print_error|e }}<br>
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\outputs\jinja\base.jinja2", line 67, in top-level template code
    {% block filter %} {% endblock %}
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\outputs\jinja\main.jinja2", line 222, in block 'filter'
    {% set title_env = environments|sort|export_environments_title %}
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\outputs\jinja_mgr.py", line 263, in _export_environments_title
    max_name = max(len(list(environment.keys())[0]) for environment in environments)
  File "Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\behavex\outputs\jinja_mgr.py", line 263, in <genexpr>
    max_name = max(len(list(environment.keys())[0]) for environment in environments)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

**Logs generated under the output folder:**
**overall_status json file contains- {"status": "skipped"}**

If any one you know, how to run the parallel scenarios using behavex, please let me know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the latest version that was released las week (BehaveX 3.0.0), as it has much better error management on unexpected parameters, and it will provide better context about the issue. Maybe the problem is in the features path you are specifying, causing an unexpected behavior in BehaveX framework.